# perform multiple & parallel login in browser in Coded UI in visual studio

Tags: automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm pretty new to coded ui test, and I'm still learning...

I am trying to create an automation script in coded UI to open multiple login page of application in browser to login in parallel manner.

I am successfully able to login sequentially (one after another) in browser.

Username and password will be fetched from an excel sheet to login.

For Example : If we have 10 users in excel sheet, and if we run the script in coded UI, 10 browsers will open and should be logged in.

Is anyone got success to achieve this?

Regards, Indrayani

Comment: I know that nobody here provides codes for the people. First try do something on your own then ask specific question(s). Good luck

Comment: For what reason would you even need to do this? Given the same browser, typically a login in one tab means you are logged in for all tabs.  Trying to login in another tab would likely require you to logout first.  Given parallel execution, you would not even know if you were logged in or if another task is about to finish logging in, etc.   Finally, if there is some requirement for this, have you considered using a Unit Test and just using HttpClient directly?